# manually set up web page link

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there in HTML,CSS or javascript some command or code with which i can change web link from C:/Users/42191/Desktop/googlepage/generator.html to idk whatever i want like www.google.com?
Thanks for advices!
[image: from this]

[image: to this]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in javascript in this way

```
    document.getElementById("myLink").onclick = function() {

        if(document.getElementById("abc").href == 
            "C:/Users/42191/Desktop/googlepage/generator.html")
        document.getElementById("abc").href="www.google.com"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url='https://www.google.com'" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Please click <a href="https://www.google.com">this link to direct now</a>.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Change 5 if you wish to redirect in less time.